# Images not loading in Gatsby project

Tags: gatsby

I have created a gatsby default project.

This is the current project structure within src folder

src

-images

-components

-assets

-pages

This is my gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `SCRUM-HR`,
    siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-image",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: './src/images/',
      },
      __key: "images"
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: "pages",
        path: './src/pages/',
      },
      __key: "pages"
    }
  ]
};
```

But when I run the page no images are visible, for example when I take a look at the property inspector in the browser, I get this message in firefox on a header styling:

```
.header {
  height: 85vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.1), rgba(40, 180, 133, 0.8)), url('/images/bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  position: relative;
}
```

for the background-image, it says:

> Could not load the image

or like this part of html:

```
<div className="composition">
            <img
              srcSet="images/skitrent-1-large.png 300w, images/skitrent-1-large.png 1000w"
              sizes="(max-width: 56.25em) 20vw, (max-width: 37.5em) 30vw, 300px"
              alt="Photo 1"
              className="composition__photo composition__photo--p1"
              src="images/skitrent-1-large.png"
            />
</div>
```

I have checked that the image do indeed exist in the src/images folder. What am I doing wrong?